# Docker-Compose network: Are duplicate IP addresses in hosts versus containers an issue?

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

Good afternoon, dear people,

I have a simple question regarding the network what is generated by `docker-compose up`:

Can it happen that the generated IP addresses 172.17.0.1 and 172.18.0.1 interfere with other servers in the host network that have the same IP addresses?

One user in the IRC spoke of a nightmare, if you want to change the IPs in Docker-Compose. Is that still the case and does anyone have a simple and secure way to change the IP?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess I don't get the point. Why are ip addresses from inside of docker be exposed to the host? Is this even be possible? I only know solutions where you map a port to the host port...

Comment: If that's the case, I'm happy! Can someone please confirm that Docker-Compose and -bridge IP addresses are only available locally on the host and do not cause problems on other hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play it safe (I'm not sure my other answer is really true):

1. Stop docker-compose if you use it (checkout dcsg for example).
2. The Docker network list can be displayed with the following command:

   ```
   docker network ls
   ```
3. Stop Docker:

   ```
   service docker stop
   ```
4. The following command shows networks (where eth0 is left untouched):

   ```
   ip route
   ```
5. Delete Docker network

   ```
   ip link del docker0
   ```
6. Verification whether deletion was successful:

   ```
   ip route
   ```
7. Create or edit file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Here you can enter your own IP range.

   ```
   {
       "bip": "192.168.3.1/24",
       "fixed-cidr": "192.168.3.1/25" 
   }
   ```
8. Start Docker:

   ```
   service docker start
   ```
9. Example `docker-compose.yml`:

   ```
   version: '3.1'
   services:
       blah:
           # ...
           # Prevent huge log files:
           logging:
               driver: "json-file"
               options:
                   max-size: "10m"
                   max-file: "10"
           networks:
               blubb:
           # ...

   networks:
       blubb:
           ipam:
               driver: default
               config:
                   - subnet: 192.168.4.0/24
   ```
10. Don't forget to (re)start Docker-Compose.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I asked again in IRC:

Is the network bridge IP created by Docker(-Compose) visible to other hosts or is it only available intern? I guess it's a network question, but in #network are only a few people :)

> The bridge is like any other interface on your linux system: it's only visible to those hosts that are directly connected to the same network, absent some sort of routing.  In a stock configuration, the only things "directly connected" to the docker bridge are (a) your host and (b) your containers, so it won't be visible to other hosts on your network.

Thanks, so other hosts in my network can have the same IP, for example 172.17.0.1... nice

> Right.

You saved my day :)